# Encryption Algorithm for Web Applications

Tags: .net, asp.net, encryption

I have been using Symmetric (Rijndael) Key Algorithm (http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx) for a while to encrypt an ID. Then I URL encode the encrypted version of the ID and pass it in the query string. When I retrieve the ID from the query string, I URL decode it first and I decrypt it.

A problem came up recently. If the encrypted ID has both "spaces" and "+" (eg "abc ef+g), URL-encoding it changes all "spaces" to "+". This is a problem when I URL-decode the ID since I don't know which "+" was a "+" and which "+" was a "space".

If there an option that I can pick the output character set to be only the alphabet (ie the encrypted ID only uses A-Z)? Or if there any other 2 way encryption algorithm that has th option for me to pick the output character set?

Or I guess my last option would be to manually replace "+" in the encrypted ID with something like "_SPACE_"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to URL encode your encrypted ID when passed as query parameters.

I prefer an URL-safe version of Base64 for anything used in query parameters or cookies.

Comment: I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() to urlencode my encrypted ID. If my encrypted ID is "abc e+", the URLencoded ID is "abc+e+". How do I URLdecode "abc+e+" later on?

Comment: Your UrlEncode() is wrong. It should output "abc+e%2b". + should always be encoded. Besides, you shouldn't use space in the ID. It should be Base64-encoded string.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It turned out that the problem was that I was getting the querystring with HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(), which already urldecodes the querstring. I also called HttpUtility.URLDecode(). So I ended up urldecoding twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer your question at a basic level: Yes, encode the encrypted result in base64.

But I must admit, I'm pretty concerned about your approach in general.

Comment: What can I do to pass an encrypted ID in the querystring?

Comment: Well your method is fine enough, but I just wonder why you are using an approach like this, as opposed to say just a general login system to determine who can do that.

Comment: This ID is not a user ID. It's a PK of a table in my database. For security reason, I don't want the user to know the exact ID.

Comment: The general solution for that, then, would be to store a GUID against the row as well, and use that as the public identifier. Encryption is just wasting the time of your server.

Answer (score 0):

you should take a look at how I decided to manage my way of hiding id (in my case guid, but can be any encrypted string)

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032376/guid-to-base64-for-url)

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually encode the URL so the spaces are changed to `%20` instead of `+`?