# Show a GUID in 36 letters format

Tags: c#, .net, guid, base64

[GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) is big random number show in a [HEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) basis. I want to show this number in a shorter format, lets say that based on the all letters and numbers. That is a 36 basis.

Lets say that: `2f1e4fc0-81fd-11da-9156-00036a0f876a` will become as `3jEl9x6eZi`.

Is there any 'ready' algorithm for this in .Net?

it need to be bidirectional.

**Edit:** using [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is even better solution. The only problem is Base64  contains `/` char which is not compatible to use in [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

Comment: For base 64, you can substitute invalid characters with valid (but not already used) ones. IIRC, there's slightly less than 96 printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Look at my answer to see how I fixed the ==, / and + issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this is what you need: [ShortGuid - A shorter and url friendly GUID class in C#](http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/20/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing built in for such a conversion. Something close that is built in is using base 64 encoding:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(theGuid.ToByteArray())
```

Comment: Good solution. But why each string ends with '==' ? `=` it's not a valid value in Base64 format.

Comment: @Mendy: The = character is used to fill up the last character group. (It's specified in the RFC 1421 standard.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible as you presented it. You'd have to lose information:

```
>>> 16 ** len('2f1e4fc081fd11da915600036a0f876a')
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
>>> 36 ** len('3jEl9x6eZi')
3656158440062976
```

You'd need many more base 36 digits to cover all possible values. Why not just use base 64 instead? The result would be shorter (and I'm assuming this is the aim here) and there is a standard solution for that in .NET.

Comment: The value `3jEl9x6eZi` is only for example, and it is not 'real' value.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 is what I use, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032376/guid-to-base64-for-url) will fix the issue with == and / and +

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest that you will find is [Base36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) however it won't work with a GIUD type (only an Int16, Int32, or Int64).