# URL safe UUIDs in the smallest number of characters

Tags: language-agnostic, uuid

Ideally I would want something like `example.com/resources/äFg4вNгё5`, minimum number of **visible** characters, never mind that they have to be percent encoded before transmitting them over HTTP.

Can you tell a scheme which encodes 128b UUIDs into the least number of visible characters efficiently, without the results having characters which break URLs?

Comment: International characters are a bit of a can of worms still; it may work while always in the browser, but if you're copy-pasting in different applications, such as a mail client, an instant messenger, or, the most fragile case, SMS, they'll break. Base64 as suggested by the answers is still the best approach unless you make the dangerous assumption that users won't use these links outside the same web browser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Base-64 is good for this.

```
{098ef7bc-a96c-43a9-927a-912fc7471ba2}
```

could be encoded as

```
vPeOCWypqUOSepEvx0cbog
```

The usual equal-signs at the end could be dropped, as they always make the string-length a multiple of 4. And instead of `+` and `/`, you could use some safe characters. You can pick two from: `-` `.` `_` `~`

More information:

- [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#page-8)
- [Storing UUID as base64 String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772802/storing-uuid-as-base64-string) (Java)
- [guid to base64, for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032376/guid-to-base64-for-url) (C#)
- [Short GUID](http://web.archive.org/web/20100408172352/http://prettycode.org/2009/11/12/short-guid/) (C#)

Answer (score 5):

I use a url-safe base64 string. The following is some Python code that does this<sup>*</sup>.

The last line removes '=' or '==' sign that base 64 encoding likes to put on the end, they make putting the characters into a URL more difficult and are only necessary for de-encoding the information, which does not need to be done here.

```
import base64
import uuid

# get a UUID - URL safe, Base64
def get_a_Uuid():
    r_uuid = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes)
    return r_uuid.replace('=', '')
```

Above does not work for Python3. This is what I'm doing instead:

```
 r_uuid = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).decode("utf-8")
 return r_uuid.replace('=', '')
```

---

<sup>*</sup>

<sub>This *does* follow the standards: `base64.urlsafe_b64encode` follows RFC 3548 and 4648 see https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html.  Stripping `==` from base64 encoded data with known length is allowed see [RFC 4648 §3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.2).  UUID/GUID are specified in [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122);  [§4.1 Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-4.1) states "The UUID format is 16 octets".  The `base64`-fucntion encodes these 16 octets.</sub>

Comment: Does not work with python3, you should use instead : `return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).strip("=")` (works in python 2 as well, returns unicode string).

Comment: Do you save the URL safe uuid as the models uuid or convert back and forth as needed?

Comment: @ReducedGosling I save the URL safe one